# Nativescript: Module not found for element

Tags: nativescript

After npm migrate, I get the following error in my code:

Module 'nativescript-filter-select' not found for element 'nativescript-filter-select:FilterSelect'.
System.err:    > layout_base_1.CSSType is not a function

In my xml, I have used
  `xmlns:FS="nativescript-filter-select"`

and
 `<FS:FilterSelect row="5" change="changeJud" col="0" multiple="false" close="{{ closeModal }}" items="{{ judete }}" search_param="judet" primary_key="id_judet"   />`

Is there a solutin for this?

Comment: What means npm migrate? Which version of NS do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out I had to uninstall the module and reinstall it. Apparenty, only installing it (without being uninstalled first) did not do the trick.